# Strange Boot Issue Fixed Itself?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm trying to understand why I had a boot issue that apparently fixed itself, partly for my education, but also to prevent it from happening again if possible. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux, and I can't figure this out. If any GRUB / boot expert can chime in, I would appreciate it!

Recently I walked away from my system when it was running, then upon returning found a black screen with a single cursor in the upper-left. I tried some key presses, but determined something had gone wrong and crashed, so I hit the hardware reset button. On boot, I got something like "Cannot find boot device", or similar message from my MB when it can't find bootable media.

I restarted several times, always with the same error. I went into BIOS and saw that my boot disk (SSD) was there, and selected correctly as the primary boot device. I looked around in BIOS, but didn't make any changes. I restarted the system several times after that, with no luck. I probably tried resetting a total of 5 or 6 times throughout this time, and feared my disk had gone bad.

Finally, I pulled out my Ubuntu USB stick that I used for installation several years ago. When inserting that and rebooting, rather than boot from USB, GRUB showed up with my HD decryption prompt, and then it booted normally! I've since rebooted again without the USB stick, and it's working fine. It's acting like nothing was ever wrong!

Some background:

- I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for over 3 years now, without any significant problems.
- Boot and data disk partitions are encrypted, but there never was any dual boot and only Ubuntu was installed from a clean disk.
- I don't recall running any updates prior to this issue, and certainly nothing that required a restart like a kernel update.

Any ideas what happened? Also, could Ubuntu GRUB/boot have somehow self-healed after booting from a USB stick? How? Finally, is this an indication of some deep underlying problem that might crop up again?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: "Also, could Ubuntu GRUB/boot have somehow self-healed after booting from a USB stick?". The only idea I can come up with: hardware did not do what was expected and it then did. It could be a timing issue: if a disk is not ready then the next time it could be ready. Generally those get you a longer boot and then an error

Comment: @Rinzwind if that's the case then I hope it was a curious fluke rather than a sign of impending failure. Though I even had power off overnight, so I think it's a stretch to believe it was coincidence and unrelated to the USB stick being plugged in.